# How to load Magritte Seaside?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside, metacello

I've loaded Magritte and Seaside from the configuration browser into Pharo 4, but I don't see that the package Magritte-Seaside was loaded.

How do I load this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the group `Seaside` defined as a Metacello group in the configuration's baseline for 3.3 (which is used by 3.5, the current version). So I was able to load the package by evaluating:

```
(ConfigurationOfMagritte3 project version: #stable) load: 'Seaside'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you loading the Stephan's QCMagritte package which includes the correct directives to load Seaside 3 with a Zinc adaptor so you can start a web server without loading anything else:

From MinGW command line:

```
    $ wget -O- http://get.pharo.org/40+vm | bash
    $ ./pharo-vm/Pharo.exe Pharo.image config \
         "http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Pharo/MetaRepoForPharo40" \
         "ConfigurationOfQCMagritte" --printVersion --install=stable --group=All
```

Create an adaptor, start a web server with the Seaside Control Panel on port 8080, and then point your browser to http://localhost:8080/browse to see applications

Answer (score 0):

The configuration browser only loads default groups for the configurations it loads. In the ConfigurationOfSeaside and ConfigurationOfMagritte you'll find many more groups.

In the ConfigurationOfQCMagritte I use 'Seaside' from Magritte and #('JQueryUI' 'JQuery-JSON') from Seaside. If you don't mind the extra packages, you could just load QCMagritte from the configuration browser.

To just add the missing packages, you could load the latest Magritte-Seaside and Magritte-Pharo-Seaside packages from the Magritte3 smalltalkhub repository with the Monticello Browser.

A pre-loaded QCMagritte image is available from http:ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/QCMagritte

Comment: Thank you. My only worry with loading from Monticello is that I am not sure how to get the right version. Could you provide a code snippet that uses Metacello / ConfigurationOfMagritte3 to load the best version of the package based on what is already loaded?

Comment: Easiest is just load QCMagritte stable from the configuration browser. If you check the contents of the package cache, you'll see what is loaded extra/different. It just adds Bootstrap, Bootstrap-Magritte and some Magritte extensions